# How do I show alt text when hovering over an anchor with a mouse?

Tags: html5

I'd like to show some descriptive text when the mouse hovers on a link:

`<a class="foo" alt="Hello World" href="/index.html">Hello World</a>`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines. In its current form, this question does *not* meet their guidelines.

Answer (score 4):

Go ahead and use the title attribute my friend!

```
<a href="#" title="hello universe!">Hello Everyone!</a>
```

Comment: Easy peezy, lemon squeezy!

Answer (score 1):

> What purpose do alt tags serve?
>
> Search engines and other robots cannot interpret images, but images
>   can play a crucial part in how people interpret a particular web page.
>   Alt tags solve for this by providing text which is read by the search
>   engines. When Googlebot or other search engine crawlers inspect a
>   page, images with properly formatted alt text contribute to how the
>   page is indexed and where it ranks.
>
> Alt tags are also useful for users viewing a webpage on screen readers or browsers that can't process images.

Source: [What is an alt tag, and how does it impact SEO?](https://www.bigcommerce.co.uk/ecommerce-answers/what-is-an-alt-tag-and-how-does-it-impact-seo/)

But in your case you would like to use a href only for hyper link so use title tag only not alt tag.

```
<ul>
 <li><a class="navbar" title="culture" href="../cultura/index.html">Cultura</a></li>
</ul>
```

If you're going to use img src then use alt tag it'll be more helpful.

Alt text is contained within the image tag example:

```
<img src="/demo/nike_air_zoom.png" alt="nike air zoom" title="nike air zoom" />
```

Comment: Please quote your sources. However, since you're going into detail describing what the "alt tag" is, I think you should at least mention that it isn't actually a valid attribute on anchors.